# Edit: R simulation study calling function

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I spend multiple hours of thinking about the following problem. I am running a simulation study and I want to define functions outside the simulation study in order to be able to call these functions in the end of my code.

A very simplified example:

Mat represents just a matrix with numbers and res is an empty matrix that I want to fill.

```
mat <- matrix(data = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ncol = 2, nrow = 3)
res <- matrix(NA, ncol = 2, nrow = 3)
```

I use the function "fun" to fill the empty matrix res.

```
fun <- function() {
  for (i in 1:2) {
    res[y,i] <- mat[y,i]
  }
  return(res)
}
```

This is what I would like to put in the end of my code (I just want to call the function and with this function I want to fill the matrix "res"). However, if I use the code below R only fills the third row and not the first and second row.

```
for (y in 1:3) {
  test <- fun()
}
```

My question is: why isn't R also filling the first and second row and how can I change my code in such a way that R provides me with the desired result?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

The following example also illustrates my problem. I make use of the "metafor" package for doing a meta-analysis.

I would like to use the following function that I define outside my final simulation code:

```
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 8, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c("0_le", "0_ri", ".13_le", ".13_ri", ".33_le", ".33_ri", ".5_le", ".5_ri"), c("1", "2", "3")))

funtr.stu <- function(i) {
  for (y in 1:8) {
    mat[y,i] <- tr[[y]]$k0
  }
  return(mat)
}
```

"tr" is a list and consists of the results of 8 times an analysis. I want to retrieve the object "k0" from that list and store it into the matrix "mat".

In the following part of the code (in which I run the simulation), I want to call the function and fill the matrix "mat" with the correct numbers.

```
for (i in 1:iterations) { 
   kip <- funtr.stu()
}
```

The result of this code is a filled matrix, but within each column the same numbers. Thus, R isn´t storing the numbers every iteration, but stores only the last iteration.

How can I modify my code in such a way that R is storing the output as I want?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is the question here?  Do you want to know how to fill a matrix with data?  Because if that's all, then `res<-matrix(data=mat,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)` or "byrow=FALSE" will write the values in `mat` into `res` in one order or another.  Then there's  `mat2<-t(mat1)` and plenty of other ways to reorder or reshape a matrix.

Comment: Dear Carl, My question is how can I get the complete matrix "res" (so not only the third row). Of course, I know that if I would only want to fill a matrix this is not a proper solution. However, I created such a simplified situation in order to illustrate the problem at hand.

Comment: Your example is too simplified. It is hard to understand what you are up to. Consider to give another example.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are overwriting all values of the matrix `test` in each iteration. I added `print(test)` in the loop. See the code.

```
mat <- matrix(data = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ncol = 2, nrow = 3)
res <- matrix(NA, ncol = 2, nrow = 3)

mat
res

fun <- function() {
  for (i in 1:2) {
    res[y,i] <- mat[y,i]
  }
  return(res)
}

for (y in 1:3) {
  test <- fun()
  print(test)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I know what is exactly going on. How can I program it in such a way that I get my results in a single matrix? So, not in three matrices as created with the print(test) command.

Comment: (+1) "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your case. Basically, return one row in each iteration of the for loop. Where as you are returning the entire 'res' matrix.

```
mat <- matrix(data = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ncol = 2, nrow = 3)
res <- matrix(NA, ncol = 2, nrow = 3)

fun <- function() {
  for (i in 1:2) {
    res[y,i] <- mat[y,i]
  }
  return(res[y,])
}

for (y in 1:3) {
  test[y,] <- fun()
}
```